# adding a module to popup

Tags: javascript, php, opencart2.x

opencart 2,3,0,2, journal,
in Journal a popup register is made. works perfect.
i added to account layout one of my module. it works very well in register but popup. my module is not loading in popup.
opened journal/account/register.tpl, tried to call my module,
$data['my module'] = $this->load->controller('extension/module/my module'); or 
of course none of them worked.

popup javascript is not a layout so i can not add a module to be seen.

how can i add my module to popup javacript? or i should think different way?